# Diffeomorphism between a solvable Lie group and $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

The following result seems to be well-known.

> If $\mathfrak{g}$ is a real finite-dimensional solvable Lie algebra and $G$ is the corresponding connected simply connected Lie group, then $G$ is diffeomorphic to the Euclidean space via the canonical coordinates of the second kind.

I think that I am misunderstanding this result.

Consider the solvable three-dimensional Lie algebra (Bianchi $VII_\beta$ with $\beta = 0$, [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_low-dimensional_real_Lie_algebras#Three-dimensional)) whose commutators satisfy
$$ [e_1,e_3] = - e_2, \quad [e_2,e_3] = e_1, \quad [e_1, e_2] = 0.  $$
We can represent this algebra as the matrix algebra spanned by the matrices
$$ e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0& 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 &0 \end{pmatrix},
\quad e_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0& 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 &0 \end{pmatrix},
\quad e_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1& 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 &0 \end{pmatrix}. $$
However, the canonical coordinates of the second kind
$$ \mathbb{R}^3 \ni x \mapsto \text{Exp}(x_1e_1) \, \text{Exp}(x_2e_2) \,\text{Exp}(x_3e_3) = \begin{pmatrix} \cos x_3 & -\sin x_3 & x_1\\ \sin x_3 & \cos x_3 & x_2\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
do not form a diffeomorphism, as the map is not even injective.

**Question:** Where does this example break down?

Comment: For the diffeomorphism see Varadarajan, Theorem $3.18.11$; we need that $\mathfrak{h}_i$ is an ideal in $\mathfrak{h}_{i+1}$, where $\mathfrak{h}_i=\sum_{1\le j \le i}\Bbb Re_j$.

Comment: Ah I see. Many thanks @DietrichBurde

Comment: Hint: This group is not simply connected.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I see it now. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: If you need a faithful linear representation, you can take a $3+1$ block decomposition, with your representation in the $3\times 3$ block and $(e_1,e_2,e_3)\mapsto (0,0,1)$ in the additional block.

Comment: Interesting, thanks @YCor. If I understand you correctly this will give me a faithful linear representation of a Lie group with the Lie algebra from the post. As far as the Lie algebra itself goes, the representation of that I give in the post should be faithful, right?

Comment: Yes, you have a faithful rep of the Lie algebra, but this only ensures that the kernel of the simply connected Lie group representation is discrete. The additional 1-dim block is faithful on that kernel, so altogether this makes a faithful rep.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks.